# Propel version with symfony 1.4.11

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I went through few post but didn't find an answer to probably one of most simple questions. What is the **standard** Propel version that comes bundled with symfony 1.4.11?

In one answer, I found a recommendation to use the `awk` command but unfortunately I'm on Windows, so that command will not run for me.

Another answer was to install different Propel Lib; please, no such answers.

Comment: Have a look inside the /lib/symfony/vendors/propel folder (it's something like that, from memory). I would imagine it is version 1.3.x. I forget which file it is, but the version number is definitely in there (Propel.php?). I think it is a PHP class constant.

Comment: Incidentally, why don't you want people to recommend you upgrade? You really _should_ install the 1.6.x plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking the folder but not found till now. Probably its plugins folder.
Upgrade is not possible as I need just to fix few minor feature enhancements on existing Symfony project (& I never worked with symfony before - headbang)

Comment: I found this line in propel.php **@version    $Revision: 1691 $**. 
Can we figure out exact version with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give a look to the [svn repository](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_4_11/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor). Each symfony version are tagged.
You will see:

> propel http://propel.mirror.svn.symfony-project.com/tags/1.4.2/runtime/classes/propel/

So it uses Propel 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the answer is Propel 1.4.2. I'm looking at the CHANGELOG file from Symfony 1.4.11 (on the [Github mirror](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/74817d929577c3ee5fd08648f6d558e199169e35/CHANGELOG)). The last change to the Propel version was in Symfony 1.4.5:

```
05/31/10: Version 1.4.5
-----------------------
[snip]
 * [29218] updated Propel to 1.4.2
```

---

Edit: indeed this is made clear in the [main `Propel` class on line 93](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/74817d929577c3ee5fd08648f6d558e199169e35/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/Propel.php#L93):

```
const VERSION = '1.4.2';
```

You can see this in your local system; the file is  `lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/Propel.php`.

Comment: Thanks for ans lonesomeday. Even if its 1.4.5, it solves my purpose. I was mainly interested to know if I could use new code (without criteria) provided with Propel 1.5. Answer probably seems to be 'No'.