# Model not being autoloaded in symfony 1.3

Tags: php, symfony1, propel, symfony-1.3

I have a table in my database called `student`, and when I try using

```
StudentPeer::retreiveByPk($stid)
```

I get a fatal error saying

> Call to undefined method StudentPeer::retreiveByPk

Is there a way I could load my model dynamically? Is there a way I could see all the models that have been auto-loaded? Also is there a way for auto-loading my model for this module?

I am using symfony 1.3.

Comment: 'Call to undefined method ... ' sounds like the class could be loaded but the method does not exist.

Comment: As an aside, while it's worth mentioning you're using symfony, the really useful info to include in questions such as these is the version of _Propel_ you're using. I believe you're using Propel 1.4, since symfony 1.3 and symfony 1.4 are identical except for the removal of deprecated classes. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156611/propel-version-with-symfony-1-4-11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mispelled the method call - it should be `StudentPeer::retrieveByPk($stid)`. The model should auto-load fine, but I wouldn't expect it to on undefined methods.